# Limits Convergence and Absolute convergence

Tags: analysis

If $a_{n}$ is an arithmetical progression and $|\lambda|<1$ then how can we prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}\lambda^{n}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a_n$ is an arithmetical progression then $a_n=a_0+n\alpha$ hence it suffices to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\lambda^n=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$c_n:=n\lambda^n\implies \sqrt[n]{|n\lambda^n|}=|\lambda|\sqrt[n]n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}|\lambda|<1\implies$$

By the $\;n-$th square root test, the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\;\;\text{ converges and thus}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=0$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition of arithmetical progression, $a_n=an+b$ for some constants $a,b$. And 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}\lambda^{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(an+b)\lambda^{n}=\cdots$$